# FileZilla FTPS on Azure VM

Tags: virtual-machines, azure, ftps

I'm looking for how to get FTPS working properly via FileZilla Server on an Azure VM running Windows 2012.  I've opened port 990 and configured FTP over TLS in FileZilla.  I have opened port 990 in both the firewall and the Azure portal interface and still cannot connect.

I'm attempting to connect using FileZilla client using FTPS login.  Has anyone succeeded in configuring an FTPS server (other than IIS) on an Azure VM?  I need separate user accounts and the ability to assign separate folders to save files to.

Any ideas?

Comment: Server logs? Client logs? Packet captures, etc? We need something to go on...

Comment: You seem to confuse SFTP with FTP over TLS. Which one do you mean?

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying, FileZilla doesn't appear to support SFTP, so I am trying to set up FTPS.  I am not getting any logs as of yet because I think the firewall or Azure endpoints are not letting the requests through.

Answer (score 1):

Too long for a comment:

Port 990 is for implicit SSL and **implicit SSL is deprecated**.

You should be using  explicit SSL  as described in [RFC 4217](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4217) which will use the regular FTP port to establish a control connection, TCP 21 and then upgrade to TLS.

Opening up a single port is going to be insufficient for [FTPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FTPS) as the protocol is exactly  like regular FTP and similarly makes do with **two connections**, one for the control connection and a second for the data connection.

Unless explicitly configured otherwise the second connection will be to a random unused TCP port and thus currently denied by your firewall configuration.

This problem can be solved with the use of a limited range of ports for the data connection and configuring the firewall to open these ports.